# Is it possible to let the compiler chose the appropriate value type for a template method argument?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

If your method or function accepts an `int` for reading only, you'd probably write it like this:

```cpp
// you may or may not write const, in this case it's an implementation detail
void muFunction(int value);
```

But if you're taking an `std::vector` you would presumably write something like this:

```cpp
void myFunction(const std::vector& value);
```

Now as far as I know, the reason for not taking an `int` or `bool` by reference is that both are just numbers and the overhead of making them a reference is more costly than just copying them. For more complicated structures however, using a const reference avoids unnecessary copy when you just want to read the data anyway.

The thing is, what if I have templated method like this:

```cpp
// double, const char*, std::string and bool are all expected types of TVal
template <typename TVal>
void myFunc(const TVal& val);
```

So here it looks like I will be unnecessary creating a reference for simple types like `bool` or `float`. Is this something C++ compilers can figure on their own and avoid? If not, is there a reasonable way to write code that does not have this problem?

Comment: Unless you have performance numbers telling you that `void myFunc(const TVal& val);` is actually slowing you down for small types, I would just stick with it.  Ideally since it is a reference the compiler can directly refer to the object and no copy/indirection needs to happen.

Comment: I mean, you could provide a pair of template overloads, and distinguish them either by `is_fundamental` or the sizeof the argument compared to the size of the native word... But it's a cognitive burden to maintain.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yeah I have no numbers. I really never thought about this before, and it probably did no harm.

Comment: There may be a tiny cost when passing an `int` by reference instead of value, but having to maintain two different versions of the same function to to save that tiny bit of performance really isn't worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, templates are header only utilities. Their implementation is visible in every translation unit(not sure about the new module mechanism; I gotta study more); which makes them good candidates for all sort of auto optimization. Unless a runtime pointer to an instance of the template is generated, the compiler tries to optimize the code out. So, most of the time, those marginal cases don't have much overhead- aside from compile-time. But you can manually optimize for small values; C++ concepts provide the mechanism to properly overload functions for small values. The problem is however, that you get to copy the same code at least twice and might decrease the readability of your code for a premature optimization with not much significant effects.

Comment: The story is equivalent with modules: the compiler just hopefully loads the template definition faster in a preparsed form.

Comment: @DavisHerring AFIAK, the module proposal was supposed to hide the implementation and transfer the code in more binary form, hopefully with good impacts on static/external initialization order.  By decreased visibility of code, I guess optimization chances might drop a bit.

Comment: All of that is true, but high-quality implementations are likely to have the same optimization opportunities since they still have to instantiate the template for types unique to the importer.